# Are electrons moving? If so relative to whom? and why is there no magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

electrons on earth **moving** with us, due to rotation of earth,    revolution of earth, sun and our galaxy right?
Then, why is there **no** magnetic field around a **piece** of copper wire?

Answer (score 2):

Because along with electrons there are also protons who also move with the copper wire. They have opposite charge, so create magnetic field of the opposite direction. The electrons' and protons' magnetic fields cancel each other.

Answer (score 2):

To good approximation Earth is an Inertial System. Charges at rest with us in this inertial system do not produce a magnetic field, as Maxwell's equations hold in any Inertial system. Viewed from another Inertial system magnetic fields of electrons and protons cancel, as explained in answer (1). Viewed in the Earth's Intertial system protons are needed to compensate the Coulomb field produced the electrons at rest with respect to us. You see here that what is a magnetic field to the one inertial system is a Coulomb field as viewed from the other system.